# Save and close all excel files with autohotkey

Tags: excel, autohotkey

I'm trying to create an ahk script to save and close all excel files I have open, however I'm struggling.

I've tried this but get errors on two lines (see below):

```
Excel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
loop % Excel.workbooks.count ;i get an error on this line
    if fileexist(Excel.workbooks(a_index).fullname)
        Excel.Workbooks(a_index).save
excel.quit() ;i get an error on this line
```

And I've tried this, but again I get errors:

```
xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
for wrkbk in xl.workbooks ;i get an error on this line
    wrkbk.close(1)
xl.quit() ;i get an error on this line
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [loop](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Loop.htm) command has to be followed by a {...} block if you have more than one statements (commands, assignments, function calls etc.) within the loop:

```
Excel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
loop % Excel.workbooks.count
{
    if fileexist(Excel.workbooks(a_index).fullname)
        Excel.Workbooks(a_index).save
}
excel.quit()
```

Comment: While this is true, that couldn't be the problem here. They do have only one statement, an if statement (and its body). The syntax is correct.

Comment: Yeah i still get an error on the loop and the excel.quit line with your example

Comment: Works fine here (Excel 2010, Win10).

Comment: Yeah strangely working now. Thanks